# django cms and responsive images

Tags: django, responsive-design, django-cms, srcset

I'm  building an responsive website with django and django-cms. So far everything is fine. Now I'm at the point that I need to specify and to deliver responsive images to different devices. How do you solve this problem for yourself?

Is there a possibility for the website-author to upload in the backend a picture in different sizes (like small, medium, large) to use with srcset (maybe with [django-cascade](http://djangocms-cascade.readthedocs.org/en/latest/bootstrap3/image-picture.html)) Or are there automated solutions for django and django-cms like the php-project [adaptive images](http://adaptive-images.com).

I found django-daguerre but I'm not shure how it can be implemented with django-cms. There is also the [django-responsive-images](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-responsive-images) 1.0.2 package.

So I want to ask you how you solve this problem for your projects.

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at the VersatileImageField; https://github.com/WGBH/django-versatileimagefield
I've not used it yet, but came across it last week & it looks like you can specify a point on an image which is the focal point, then decide what size to display it within your templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I do for responsive (and retina) images in djangocms.

1. I use the `THUMBNAIL_HIGH_RESOLUTION = True` setting of [`easy_thumbnails`](http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/settings/#easy_thumbnails.conf.Settings.THUMBNAIL_HIGHRES_INFIX)
2. I use [`cmsplugin_filer_image`](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/cmsplugin-filer/tree/develop/cmsplugin_filer_image) for my images. I overwrite its template [`default.html`](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/cmsplugin-filer/blob/develop/cmsplugin_filer_image/templates/cmsplugin_filer_image/plugins/image/default.html) by adding [`srcset`](https://responsiveimages.org/) and Twitter bootstrap's [`img-responsive`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images) class to the `img` tags in the template.

You could of course also use foundation's [interchange](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html), [retina.js](http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/) or your own css/js solution to grab the desired pictures for the respective resolutions.